# Interesting Surd Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals

If $  x  $, $  y  $ and $  z  $ are rational numbers such that
$  \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2}-1} = \sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}+\sqrt[3]{z}$ then find $ x,y,z $

Answer (score 3):

Firstly:

$${2}^{1/3}-1=(x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}+z^{1/3})^3=x+y+z+...=\frac mn+...$$

$${2}^{1/3}=\frac mn+1+...$$

Now you should show that in such case $m/n\equiv-1$, so $m+n=0$

Comment: That means your ... is equal to $2^(1/3)$. How do you know that?
Also, in the question, m and n are POSITIVE integers. Then $0$ is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Srinivasa Ramanujan,
$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}
=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{9}}
-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{9}}
+\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}}$.

Comment: Where is the proof?

Comment: That's based on the identity $${\sqrt[3]{(m^{2}+mn+n^{2}) \sqrt[3]{(m-n)(m+2n)(2m+n)}+3mn^{2}+n^{3}-m^{3}\,}} \\=\sqrt[3]{\frac{(m-n)(m+2n)^{2}}{9}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{(2m+n)(m-n)^{2}}{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{(m+2n)(2m+n)^{2}}{9}}$$  By the way, most Ramanujan's discoveries came from his own instinct intuition.